# How do I use the S3 bucket arn from a terraform module output with a count index?

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform module that creates an S3 bucket based on a variable creates3bucket is true or false.

The resource block looks like this.

```
#Codepipeline s3 bucket artifact store
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "LambdaCodePipelineBucket" {
  count = var.creates3bucket ? 1 : 0
  bucket = var.lambdacodepipelinebucketname
}
```

I output the bucket arn in the outputs.tf file like this.

```
output "codepipelines3bucketarn"{
    description = "CodePipeline S3 Bucket arn"
    value = aws_s3_bucket.LambdaCodePipelineBucket[*].arn
}
```

From the calling module I want to pass this arn value in the bucket policy. This works fine when the bucket is not an indexed resource. But Terraform plan complains when there is a count associated with the bucket.

From the calling module I pass the bucket policy like this:

```
cps3bucketpolicy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Id      = "LambdaCodePipelineBucketPolicy"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid    = "AllowPipelineRoles"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          AWS = ["${module.lambdapipeline.codepipelinerolearn}"]
        }
        Action = "s3:*"
        Resource = [
          "${module.lambdapipeline.codepipelines3bucketarn}",
          "${module.lambdapipeline.codepipelines3bucketarn}/*",
        ]
      },
      {
        Sid : "AllowSSLRequestsOnly",
        Effect : "Deny",
        Principal : "*",
        Action : "*",
        Resource : [
          "${module.lambdapipeline.codepipelines3bucketarn}",
          "${module.lambdapipeline.codepipelines3bucketarn}/*",
        ],
        Condition : {
          Bool : {
            "aws:SecureTransport" : "false"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
```

Terraform Plan error: So for some reason once i added the count to the s3 bucket resource terraform does not like the  "${module.lambdapipeline.codepipelines3bucketarn}/*" in the policy.

[image: Error screenshot]

How do I pass the bucket arn in the policy from the calling module?

Comment: It doesn't like it because the way you currently reference it means that there is only one value. Since you created buckets using the `count` meta-argument it will be an array, meaning you can access buckets with `[0]`, `[1]` etc. So in the resource/module you are creating a bucket policy you could add the `count` meta-argument and then use `${module.lambdapipeline.codepipelines3bucketarn[count.index]`.

Answer (score 1):

Like Marko E. wrote, you need to use the indexed resource. In your case, you should use this:

```
output "codepipelines3bucketarn"{
    description = "CodePipeline S3 Bucket arn"
    value = aws_s3_bucket.LambdaCodePipelineBucket[0].arn
}
```

But, in your case, your output would be empty, if the variable var.creates3bucket is false.

So I conclude, eighter the bucket is available or you will create it. If this is the case, use the data source for your policy.

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "LambdaCodePipelineBucket" {
  bucket = var.lambdacodepipelinebucketname
}
```

and change in your policy

```
"${module.lambdapipeline.codepipelines3bucketarn}"
```

to

```
"${data.aws_s3_bucket.LambdaCodePipelineBucket.arn"
```

Now, the only "error" will be, if the bucket is not available (then justs set your variable to true and the data source will find a bucket.

Comment: Data source won't work for this at all. Your example is not at all how data sources work. First, a data source is checked before any resources are created, so if the resource is created in the same code as the data source, it will never be found. Second, if a data source item is not found, terraform throws an error and exits, so in the event that `creates3bucket` is `false` that's not going to work anyway.

Comment: it will be possible, if you are using e.g. the **depends_on**. You can specify there, that your "creates3bucket" must applied before you use them. If the bucket not exists, and you also won't create it, you should try to use the same logic with count. This is possible, so using count for data source and also for all dependencies based on this data source.

Comment: So you're saying they should have a `data "aws_s3_bucket"` that `depends_on` the `resource "aws_s3_bucket"`? Can you not see how that is pointless, when they could just reference the `resource.aws_s3_bucket` directly? And since they have to have the same `count` on both of them, then what problem in the original question is the data source solving?

Comment: as far as I understood was: eighter the will create the bucket or they will use an existing one. If they want to use an existing one, they can use the data source for this. If they want to create this bucket, they can also use the data source, but use the depends_on, so that the data source will be able to find this currently newly created bucket. If they are using separate modules for this, they can use depends_on for the "second" module, where they want to create the policy. This "fixes" the possible upcoming issue, that data source won't be able to find the bucket.

Comment: The way I understood the question is they are either creating an S3 bucket or not. I didn't get any indication that they were using a bucket that already exists in the event that they aren't creating a bucket. On re-read I think the question is too vague. It's not clear to me what they want exactly.